# Question about best way to structure my data in specific loop and saving

Tags: python, data-structures

I am new to python and programming. I started this summer and have been trying to use it to do chemistry research.

My goal:
Currently, my goal is to make a loop that runs a simulation that generates two float64s and a list. The float64s contain x and y values for a plot and I am looking to save each output as x and y coordinates and then save them to a single data structure so I can call on them later for machine learning (haven't gotten to that point yet).

What I was going to try:
I was told that a list might be the best way to store the values for this because I will be generating something like 10000 iterations of this with about 1000 x and y points each iteration. I was thinking I could have a loop to store each set of x and y as lists in two other lists and at the end change them into some sort of csv file. I am worried this will be very inefficient and thought I could put the question out there.

My current code:

```
x_list = []
y_list = []


count = 0
while count < 2:    
    df = *this is a function I am not sure I can share the name of*
    
    x_arr = df[0]
    y_arr = df[1]
    k = df[2]
    
    x_axis = x_arr.tolist()
    y_axis = y_arr.tolist()
    
    x_list.append(x_axis)
    y_list.append(y_axis)
    
    count += 1
```

The data and data types:

```py
print(x_arr.dtype)
print(y_arr.dtype)
print(type(k))
print(len(x_list), len(y_list))

float64
float64
<class 'list'>
2 2
```

I would also appreciate recommended resources I can learn more about these questions.

Comment: You could probably just use a single list of lists like `xy_list.append([df[0],df[1]])`, so that you have a large list of x,y coordinate pairs.  Otherwise it's probably a fine approach.  If it's taking way too long to run, you'd have to disclose some approximation of what the function is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I just wanted to make sure I didn't have a huge gap in my thinking since I have had zero formal training in coding. hehe